# How to add an error or notification to an activity?

Tags: buddypress

I have a feature on my BuddyPress groups when I send out custom notifications to all members when a group activity is posted as an announcement. There is a possibility that something could go wrong of course and so I want to be able to add an error message to the activity if the notification fails to send.

Since my notification is hooked to the `bp_activity_after_save` action the update will already be posted so I still want the post to appear on the activity feed but just make the user aware that the notifications were not sent for a given reason.

`add_action( 'bp_activity_after_save', array( $this, 'send_team_notification'), 10, 1 );`

I've tried to look for a filter or something I could use to modify the content of the activity before it was posted but unfortunately I couldn't find anything of use so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enough digging I figured it out. First off you must save your error message to as activity meta data like so:

```
public function send_team_notification($activity) {
    $message = $this->send_custom_notification($activity->content);
    if(is_wp_error($message)){
        bp_activity_update_meta( $activity->id, 'custom_error', $message );
    }
}
```

This will appear in the database under the `wp_bp_activity_meta` table like so:

[image]

From there you can either manually update your theme template file, `buddypress\activity\entry.php` otherwise I chose to hook into the `bp_activity_entry_meta` action like so:

```
add_action('bp_activity_entry_meta', array( $this, 'add_activity_error') );
function add_activity_error(){
    $error = bp_activity_get_meta(bp_get_activity_id(), 'custom_error');
    _e('<div><p class="error">'.$error->get_error_message('error-code').'</p></div>');
}
```

Hope that helps!